# htaccess redirects to another port and appends keyword to my uri

Tags: php, .htaccess

Im on ubuntu and I have varnish cache, I searched my problem a lot but could not find it,

when I enter

```
http://127.0.0.1/soccer
```

This uri means require soccer.php, My browser redirects me to,

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/soccer/?tab_id=soccer
```

But when I type,

```
http://127.0.0.1/soccer/
```

this one works okay and interesting thing is, this problem only happens in "soccer" and "save" keywords,

this is my .htaccess

```
# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
# Or, compress certain file types by extension:
<files *.php>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
<files *.html>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</files>
RewriteEngine On
Options -MultiViews
RewriteRule ^([//0-9a-zçöşığüA-ZÇÖŞİĞÜ-]+)$ tab.php?tab_id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Try adding `Options -MultiViews` to your htaccess

Comment: You should add the .htaccess file content to your question as it is very relevant

Comment: I added, Options -MultiViews, does not seem to work

Comment: @pablo I added my .htaccess, I need your help

Comment: Why the double `//` in the rewrite rule?

Comment: it is for trailing slashes. / or // gives me the same result

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is probably mod_dir interferring with the processing of your URI. By default, if mod_dir is loaded, it'll add a trailing slash to the end of a URI that it thinks maps to a directory when the trailing slash is missing. This causes issues when the URL/File mapping pipeline causes what looks like a directory to be processed by a file (e.g. via mod_rewrite), mod_dir doesn't know because this happens further down the pipeline, thus mod_dir marks the URI to be a redirect, then other things happen to it further down (or up) in the pipeline, finally resulting in a URI that got processed by multiple modules that got redirected when the redirect shouldn't have happened.

To clarify, when I mean "*it'll add a trailing slash to the end of a URI*", I mean that mod_dir 302 redirects the browser to the same URI except it ends with a trailing slash.

You can try a couple of things:

1. Turn off mod_dir by including a `DirectorySlash Off`. This makes it so mod_dir won't redirect the browser, but [note that there are other consequences to turning this off](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash). You can add that directive in your htaccess file.
2. Handle the trailing slash in mod_rewrite:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   Options -MultiViews

   RewriteRule ^([//0-9a-zçöşığüA-ZÇÖŞİĞÜ-]+)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
   RewriteRule ^([//0-9a-zçöşığüA-ZÇÖŞİĞÜ-]+)/$ tab.php?tab_id=$1 [QSA,L]
   ```