# htaccess - trailing slash url

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Hello I have the following problem: I have some pages (php includes) which I load them like this

```
http://www.domain.com/news/
```

they work perfect. But if I remove the trailing slash

```
http://www.domain.com/news
```

this happens -> `http://www.domain.com/news/?page=news&request=`

Here are my htaccess rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

<IfModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on       Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk  Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file      \.(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl|jpg|png|gif)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler   ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime      ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime      ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</IfModule>




Options -Indexes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)(.*)$ /index.php?page=$1&request=$2
```

PS. Could it by because I have a news folder in the root document as well ?

Comment: What is the desired result if you visit `domain.com/news/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's because you have a `news/` folder in the root. Your Rewrite Condition is looking for anything that isn't a file (i.e. `!-f`) or a directory (`!-d`). Try renaming your `news/` directory in the root.

If you must, you can force `domain.com/news` to rewrite to `domain.com/news/` by doing the following:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Yep the directory was the issue, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a mod_dir issue. It's redirecting the browser when it thinks a URL maps to a directory (even if it's later determined not to) to ensure that a trailing slash is appended to the end. [See this recent explanation that I posted in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13849773/851273).

Like in the other answer, you can either turn off `DirectorySlash` or ensure that all of the affected URL's get redirected with a trailing slash via mod_rewrite (so that the rewrite **and** the redirect happens within the same module):

1. Turn off mod_dir by including a `DirectorySlash Off`. This makes it so mod_dir won't redirect the browser, but [note that there are other consequences to turning this off](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash). You can add that directive in your htaccess file.
2. Handle the trailing slash in mod_rewrite:

   ```
   RewriteEngine On
   Options -MultiViews

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]
   ```